# Turn around vector without Java

Tags: android, xml, animation, vector

I have a vector (which is an image located in my drawable folder) :

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="45dp"
    android:height="45dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M12,4L12,1L8,5l4,4L12,6c3.31,0 6,2.69 6,6 0,1.01 -0.25,1.97 -0.7,2.8l1.46,1.46C19.54,15.03 20,13.57 20,12c0,-4.42 -3.58,-8 -8,-8zM12,18c-3.31,0 -6,-2.69 -6,-6 0,-1.01 0.25,-1.97 0.7,-2.8L5.24,7.74C4.46,8.97 4,10.43 4,12c0,4.42 3.58,8 8,8v3l4,-4 -4,-4v3z" />
</vector>
```

I would like this vector to turn round and round indefinitely (like an animation or a GIF), **but without using java code!**

There are already lots of questions about adding an animation to a vector, however I've found no answer only with XML code.

Is it even possible? If it is, does someone know how to do it?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

**Edit: API level 19**

Comment: Did you look https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable

Comment: @lllllllllllllll "I would like this vector to turn round and round indefinitely (like an animation or a GIF), **but without using java code!**"

Comment: so you want animation to your vector

Comment: @PankajKumar yes, but the tablet I have to use for this app is in API level 19 only and it seems that this feature was added in API level 21

Comment: for what you need animation can you please tell

Comment: @NayMak https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat in that case.

Comment: @lllllllllllllll I need an animation on my vector. My vector is an image and I want it to turn round and round indefinitely. I would like this vector to be animated immediately when I add it to an ImageView **without using Java** to do it.

Comment: you can I use after effects to animate but it is hard ..but you Can get free  animation by Lottie just give a Try or if there is problem, come back

Comment: yes you can do this..I ll show you how

Answer (score 0):

**yes you can create animated vector by your own or else you can get free animated vector in LOTTIE**

[this is the source code](https://github.com/rgdixit/AnimatedClockDrawable)

[look how to create vector animation](https://haptik.ai/tech/animated-vector-drawables-1/)

[look this for AnimatedVectorDrawable documentary](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable)

[take a look at this for free ready made animationVector by Lottie](https://www.lottiefiles.com)

you can create your own using after effects and Bodymovin you can see lot of tutorials in youtube **I think this is helpfull**